# Excel VBA: Nonexistant macro showing in macro list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly large VBA Library for Excel, that I have been buildung up over time. Today I noticed, that there is a marco in the list in Excel, that does not exist.

To be more explicit:

- When opening the macro dialog for excel directly, it contains an entry "rowRasAttrValue".
- When I click the macro, I get a ref error.
- The delete button is greyed out for this macro.
- When opening the macro dialog from VBA, it is not listed.
- It is odd this name appears, as it does not exist in the library (it did at a time, but was a function anyway).

Sanity checks:

- No other workbook is open.
- I tried some idea for the opposite (macro not showing): Save under different name, open, do not activate but go to VBa directly, compile and save. Did not help.
- The macro name does not appear in the name manager.

How to fix it?

Best,

YeOldHinnerk

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: One "solution": Export all code modules and code hidden elsewhere, import it to an empty workbook, it's gone. For an empty lib that's ok - but is there a fix once the workbook has been in heavy use and you don't want to redo everything?

Comment: Screenshot won't be terribly helpful, as it just has the name of macro in the list, that does not exist. And it is indeed different between Excel and VBA. So that's how I got the idea of starting with an empty WB - I'm fairly sure nothing my code did broke it :)

Comment: I wanted a screenshot mainly to see if the edit button is greyed out as weel and what is in the "Macros in:" field just to be sure as this information is not explicitly mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I've never experienced this specific issue, but if things are as you say, it could be the result of some corrumption of the VBA project.

Indeed, as discussed on the [AppsPro website](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) :

> During the process of creating VBA programs a lot of junk code builds up in your files. If you don't clean your files periodically you will begin to experience strange problems caused by this extra baggage. Cleaning a project involves exporting the contents of all its VBComponents to text files, deleting the components and then importing the components back from the text files.

The website also offers a tool to automate this process if you have a lot of VBComponents, but it only works for 32-bit versions of Excel. You can also automate this process with VBA and there is a few tools that allow you to easily export and re-import code in your project. For example [VBA-IDE-Code-Export](https://github.com/spences10/VBA-IDE-Code-Export) or [vbaDeveloper](https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper). For vbaDeveloper, I also have a simplified installation process in [my fork](https://github.com/DecimalTurn/vbaDeveloper) if you'd like to get started faster.

At least this approach doesn't involve to start from a new workbook which is laborious if you have a lot of non-VBA content in the workbook.

---

EDIT: Also you mention that your library is large, but if one of the modules is too large (more than 64KB), it can also make this unstable.

[image]

So, make sure that you split your modules into smaller modules if they get too big ([source](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/size-limit-on-modules-in-vba.1114371/post-5367741)).

Comment: @YeOldHinnerk - If there is an issue with this answer, please let me know, so I can improve it.

Comment: The answer is broad and unspecific, not directly adressing the issue. It also requires a 3rd party tool, which may be an issue in a commercial context. Downvote was by someone else though :)

Comment: @YeOldHinnerk - one of your commenta mentioned that exporting and reimporting the module worked, so if that solution solves your problem, I'd say it's relevant even if it can solve a broader type of problems. Regarding the "3rd party tools" issue, two of them are open source, so you can always modify/copy the code and make your own solution if you prefer, but why re-invent the wheel when you don't have to?